# How include in directive a single instance dependency?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

I have a directive.

```
.directive("fileInfoWidget", function()
{
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "app/project/directives/fileInfoWidget.html"
    };
})
```

And I have bind to kendo template (in separate file) in fileInfoWidget.html.

So I need include one file with template in my page.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Unable to figure what you want to achieve...can you explicitly state what the above code's result is, and what your expectation is...

Comment: I know rules. I read documentation and I can't understand how do it at all. Now I just include <script src='customTemplate'></script> in index.html, but I what to include file onle when derective is active

Comment: to clarify: you want to include file only once when the directive is used?

Comment: But that is the default behaviour...! Angular will cache the partial file. You really don't need to rely on the script element for caching your templates always. If you want to cache the templates in the initial phases, then that approach is viable. Else just go with the default behaviour...